# convert curl command to python

Tags: python-3.x, api, curl, python-requests

I have below curl command

```
file_location='some/path/to/test.csv'

auth_token='my_api_token'

curl --insecure --request POST 'https://<ip_address>/eds/api/table/table_name/changes/addBulk?hasHeader=false' -H 'Csrf-Token: nocheck' -H 'AuthToken:'$auth_token'' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --form 'data=@'$file_location'
```

The data in csv is just multiple rows with 1 column, for example below:

```
row_1
row_2
row_3
```

The curl command works perfectly fine, I am trying to get python alternative for it, I tried below:

```
files = {'file': ('test.csv', open("some/path/to/test.csv", 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')}

auth_token="<api token here>"

url="https://" + ip_address +"/eds/api/table/" + table_name + "/changes/addBulk?hasHeader=false"

headers = {
    'Csrf-Token': 'nocheck',
    'AuthToken': auth_token
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Help with what? You seem to have already converted it.

Comment: But that is not working, unfortunately

Comment: Any error messages? Post them.

Comment: `C:\Users\karan.nayak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1043: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified 
HTTPS request is being made to host '<ip address>'. Adding certificate verification is strongly 
advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
<Response [400]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in your curl url you have "eds" before "/api/..." but in your python version you do not.

```
curl_url = "https://<ip_address>/eds/api/table/table_name/changes/addBulk?hasHeader=false"

python_url = "https://" + ip_address +"/api/table/" + table_name + "/changes/addBulk?hasHeader=false"
```

Also, in python 3 it is cleaner to use an f-string like this:

```
url = f"https://{ip_address}**/eds/**api/table/{table_name}/changes/addBulk?hasHeader=false"
```

Everything else looks right to me. In the future it may help to set a break point on the response to see if there is any additional information with the 400 http response.

EDIT:

Okay then, can you try modifying your header to be:

```
headers = {
    'Csrf-Token': 'nocheck',
    'AuthToken': auth_token,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

Also edit your files to be:

```
files = {
    'data': ('test.csv', open("some/path/to/test.csv", 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')
}
```

Final code should be:

```
auth_token = "<api token here>"
files = {
    'data': ('test.csv', open("some/path/to/test.csv", 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')
}
url = f"https://{ip_address}/eds/api/table/{table_name}/changes/addBulk?hasHeader=false"

headers = {
    'Csrf-Token': 'nocheck',
    'AuthToken': auth_token
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
```

Comment: Ah, actually that is my mistake in the post here, but my script does have the correct url... thanks for checking into this though
I edited the post, now it should have eds

Comment: Can you try the suggestions in my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried just now, but shows same error message

Comment: Sorry, I also made an additional change to your files. Did you try that as well?

Comment: Ohh, no, I didn't try that, let me do that now, thanks!!

Comment: It gives this error:


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "line 4, in <module>
    files = {'file': ('test.csv', open("some\\path\\to\\test.csv", 'rb', 'multipart/form-data'))}
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: I think we are adding `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` twice

once in files, and another one in headers

can that be reason?

Comment: Is that the exact error? Firstly, it looks like it's still using 'file' instead of 'data' per my edit. Secondly, there is a missing ) after 'rb'. Can you edit and try again. Edit: and an extra ) after ...form-data') aka ) is in the wrong place.

Comment: You were right, it was missing ')'

RE: 'data' or 'file', my requests contains file and not data, so i guess i should be okay using file instead of data, right?

`files = {'file': ('test.csv', open("some\\path\\to\\test.csv", 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244847/discussion-between-mr-mooo-cow-and-karan-nayak).

Comment: BTW - now I am again back to the original error message