# error 400 while running PUT request in python

Tags: python-3.x, api, curl, python-requests, put

I have a working curl command:

```
ip_address='<my ip address>'
sessionID='<got from post request metadata>'

curl --insecure --request PUT 'https://'$ip_address'/eds/api/context/records' -H 'Csrf-Token: nocheck' -H 'AuthToken:<token>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"sessionId": "'$session_ID'", "replace":false}'
```

The python script looks like below:

```
headers_put = {
    'Csrf-Token': 'nocheck',
    'AuthToken': '<my token here>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

url_put = "https://" + ip_address + "/eds/api/context/records"

data = { 
    "sessionId":"<session id got from POST request metadata>", 
    "replace":"false" 
}

response = requests.put(url_put, headers=headers_put, data=data, verify=False)
print(response)
```

Error message I get is:

```
<Response [400]>
b'Bad Request: Invalid Json'
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

Can this error cause because of data:

```
print(data)

{'sessionId': '<session id received from post metadata>', 'replace': 'false'}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert curl command to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72292709/convert-curl-command-to-python)

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

Http status 400 means ‘bad request’ as outlined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400).  You have omitted 1 request header (Csrf-token) in pyScript that was contained in your curl statement.  Consider including that and retry the script.

If you still receive an error - you could try and extract (in your script) the actual text or.body of the 4xx response.  It may be accessible from the `text` property of the python `response` object (you can confirm content-type) using `response.apparent_encoding`.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I tried with Csrf-Token but it gave the same error response 400

Comment: `<Response [400]>   b'Bad Request: Invalid Json' `

I am getting this error message

Comment: Hey i found the solution:


https://stackoverflow.com/a/72306356/10398542

Comment: Glad that sorted your issue! 

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

`response = requests.put(url_put, headers=headers_put, json=data, verify=False)`

instead of `data=` we have to use `json=`